# Installing JSON - Ruby, Development Kit and PATH Variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I've been having a really difficult time trying to install JSON and the Ruby development kit to get Rails to work in Windows 8. I believe JSON is getting installed, but to the wrong directory and that is why Ruby can't find it. I believe the problem lies with my PATH variable, or my directories.

When I run this command:

```
gem install json -v '1.8.1'
```

I receive the following output:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.
1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/ge
nerator/gem_make.out
```

The above output leads me to believe that the problem lies with my PATH but I can't pinpoint what exactly it is.

This line I think is the most important

```
Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.
    1 for inspection.
```

This leads me to believe JSON is installed, but not in the right directory.

After running gem install, I received this message.

```
Could not find json-1.8.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
```

Another clue that the problem might be related to the path. If it's temporarily enhancing the path, that means the path wasn't right to begin with.

This is the result of running PATH:

```
C:\Ruby200\bin; C:\Windows\system32; C:Windows\System32\Wbem; 
C:Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\SimplePass; 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared; 
C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;
C:\Users********\AppData\Roaming\npm –
```

Here is more information:

```
* Ruby Version - 2.0.0
* Operating System - Windows 8
* Platform - 64bit
* Devkit version - mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe
```

I also ran the following:

```
chdir C:\Ruby200\devkit
ruby dk.rb init
ruby dk.rb review
ruby dk.rb install
```

Here is the location of my Ruby directory:

```
C:\Ruby200
```

Here is the location of my devkit inside of my Ruby directory:

```
C:\Ruby200\devkit
```

Here are the files and directories located inside the devkit directory:

```
etc (directory)
  >fstab.sample
  >inputrc.default
  >profile
  >termcap
mingw (directory)
  >bin (directory)
  >contrib (directory)
  >include (directory)
  >lib (directory)
  >libexec (directory)
  >licenses (directory)
  >man (directory)
  >manifest (directory)
  >share (directory)
  >x86_64_w64-mingw32 (directory)
  >mingw64env.cmd
postinstall (directory)
  >pi.bat
  >pi.sh
sbin (directory)
  >awk (directory)
devkitvars.bat
devkitvars.ps1
dk.rb
m.ico
msys.bat
msys.ico
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, but as always help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I have searched every single page in Stack Overflow and still can't find an answer. This is hopeless.

Answer (score 0):

I followed

https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/issues/184

And ran

```
gem update --system 2.0.3
```

And that got rid of the error.

However, now I'm personally now getting this error when I run

```
gem install json


ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'json' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect retur
ned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (
https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Maybe you'll have better luck. It could be their servers maybe?

Comment: Well, I get the same error message, but with something added that looks similar to that message. ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'v' <>= 0) in any repository ERROR: Could not find a valid gem '1.8.1' <>= 0 in any repository. Most likely, my problem lies with my PATH variables. I think the gems did get installed, just not to the right location

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

> gem sources -a http://rubygems.org

then answer with Y and try again.

That worked form me. Good luck